# Class AB Amp slight distortion at any level

Tags: operational-amplifier, amplifier, power-amplifier

I wanted to build an amplifier for a spare set of 4 ohm 20W speakers I have laying around. After three days of searching circuits on the internet and trying them out on a breadboard not having much knowledge in amplifiers, I've finally managed to piece together this circuit that actually amplifies the signal instead of doing nothing. The problem that I'm having is, there's a slight amount of distortion at any input amplitude. RV1 has been tuned to drive the opamp just enough to 0V before the output starts clipping, directly hooking the inverting input up to 0V distorts the audio like crazy. Not having and oscilloscope and only a cheap multipeter how would I go about improving this circuit?
Changing R1 and R2 to something lower makes the problem worse, to something higher and nothing happens, above 10k and the amplification fades away signifficantly. And the LM358 is the only op-amp I have

The reason why I used MOSFETS is because I've had them laying around and nothing else.
And yes the power source is sketchy atm but that'll be changed out for a proper power source once the circuit is finalised and works without distorting.

[image: Schematic]

Comment: This circuit has a tendency to oscillate near the series resonance of \$C_{GS}\$ with \$L_S\$. about 30 MHz. Be certain to put a small resistor in series with each gate. (10 to100 ohm).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Q2 is upside down (S and D are reversed): -

[image]

You should also use a 2.2 kΩ pull-down resistor on pin 2 of U1A to 0 volts and use non-polarized 10 μF decoupling capacitors. The 100 uF electrolytic will act like a diode when Q2 is conducting so change it to 10 μF non-polarized.

And, given that you say that Q2 is connected up correctly and that only the schematic is wrong, you will need to increase the bias across the LEDs more than likely to something like 3 volts for each. This is based on the transfer characteristic graph in the IRF540N [data sheet](https://media.digikey.com/pdf/Data%20Sheets/Fairchild%20PDFs/IRF540N.pdf): -

[image]

This is the gate-source voltage that just about causes the MOSFET to begin linear conduction. Around 2 volts the MOSFET will be relying on the negative feedback of the op-amp to jump over the hump of cross-over distortion and, given that the op-amp you have used is fairly slow, you will get distortion if the biasing is much below 2.5 volts. Start with 2.5 volts is my recommendation.

You might also try a 330 Ω resistor from the op-amp output to the speaker output to allow the op-amp to handle the low power signals feeding the speaker. This will linearize things too. It's quite a common-practice.

If you are using red, green or yellow LEDs, they will only produce a forward drop of about 2 volts and, that is a little low. I'd say aim for 2.5 volts.

Comment: The op-amp is connected to the supply, to the right of the speaker, reversing S and D on Q2 results in the amp not working and both transistors getting very hot very quickly (likely just got it in reverse in KiCad)

Comment: Amplifiers need care and attention to biasing so, try shorting out one of the LEDs and see what happens. I can 100% assure you that the source of Q2 must go to the speaker output.

Comment: @mineing both getting hot quickly suggests cross-conduction where both transistors are on. Note the dual-diode biasing is designed for BJTs since the base-emitter voltage is close to the voltage of a diode and therefore it biases them properly. It doesn't work with MOSFETs where the needed bias is a different amount

Comment: Not much that's happening when shorting either LED, shorting both only makes the distortion worse..
Also, I've tried LEDs with a higher forward-voltage, result is extra heat

Comment: @greybeard the C stands for "section C of U1", that's why U1A is also labled as such, section A of U1

Comment: (@mineing: Considering it's a dual device, I'm still confused about C.)

Comment: @mineing so we've gone from "the amp not working and both transistors getting very hot very quickly" (your first comment) to "shorting both only makes the distortion worse" so, do as I suggest and short one LED and tell me what the distortion is like and wait for a few minutes to tell me how hot the transistors are getting. Of course, with the p-channel MOSFET reversed as originally fitted, it could have got damaged. Hopefully not but, you can't rule it out.

Comment: @Andyaka I've already said that only shortign one LED does nothing, and when I reverse source and drain of Q2 it **stops** working and turns into a fancy space heater, it's only reversed in the schematic

Comment: @mineing are you saying that the MOSFET was connected correctly in your real circuit but you showed it wrongly only in your schematic? Are you saying this?

Comment: @Andyaka yes I said that

looking at your edits, the best I can do for non-polarised caps is sadly 0.22µF, don't really have that many capacitors at hand..

Following Edin-Fifićs advice has the bias voltages increasing to about 2.7V, opted to use blue LEDs as they result in a same voltage while dropping battery voltage by 0.5V immediately due to the wasted heat. Adding the 330 ohm resistor definitely helps tho and dropping it down to 39 ohms almost completely gets rid of it.

Comment: 39 ohms might be asking too much of the op-amp because for the small signals that the MOSFETs are not going to be good at reproducing, the op-amp is driving the speaker via that 39 ohm and may cause damage. A faster op-amp would also improve things. 0.22 uF would ruin the bass by cutting it off too much; you really need 10 uF non-polarized caps. For the blue LEDs, try increasing R1 and R2 to about 4k7 or maybe as high as 10 k to reduce the 2.7 volts to maybe 2.6 volt or less. @mineing

Comment: @Andyaka Changing R1&2 to 4.7k and it did help (accidentally left in 1k from experimentation, whoops) and the voltage is now down to 2.5V-ish.
Since the 358 is the only opamp I have, I guess I'll have to go on a shopping spree to get a better one, which one would you recommend to buy? Thanks for all the advice tho, it definitely made things better

Comment: @mineing the TL072 (dual) springs to mind as it has a fairly good bandwidth (3 MHz from memory). The 358 is less than 1 MHz. If we're done now (you can always raise a new question of course) please read this and select an answer: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 0):

(After reading your comments, I realize you got it MADE properly, unlike what the schematic shows, so ignore this first paragraph.) 
First of all, your P-channel MOSFET drain and source pins need to be flipped around; the source pins of both MOSFETs are tied together to the output.
If your transistors conduct and get hot when you swap the drain and source of the Q2, the Q2 might be damaged. You should check it for shorts across any two of its pins, and it should act as a diode between drain and source (drain positive, source negative). Just make sure you don't turn it on with the instrument and then get a false short reading.

Second of all, you will have crossover distortion because the gate-source threshold voltage could be anywhere between 2 and 4 volts, and each of the two LEDs for the MOSFETs need to match their particular MOSFET to which they are connected (upper LED for the upper MOSFET, lower LED for the lower MOSFET). 
The idea of the LED here is to keep the MOSFETs around their threshold voltage at slight conduction to prevent crossover distortion. 
So, measure each MOSFET's threshold voltage (at which it starts turning on), and then get an appropriate LED for it:
a RED LED is typically around 1.7V, GREEN is about 2.0-2.3V, BLUE and WHITE can be from 2.6V to 3.4V. You can also combine two LEDs to get appropriate value for each, the D1 and D2 diode.

Comment: 1 - they are only flipped in the schematic, did an oopsie there, they are new FETs and work perfectly fine and it does not have shorts (except when turning it on, expected behaviour)

2 - how would I go about measuring that? The datasheet mentions a gate-threshold voltage of about 2-4V, would that be it? measuring across either LED gives me a reading of exactly +-1.93V

Comment: Yes, that would be it. You need to connect a resistor to the drain (like 1k or so) with an ammeter or LED in series. Then you slowly raise the voltage from zero to 4V while measuring it and observing the output. Once the current starts flowing (or LED glowing), that's your gate-source threshold voltage.

Comment: You can't measure that voltage with an LED in the circuit because the LED will sink it down to its own voltage. You need to measure outside of the circuit. Based on the voltage, I would say it's a green LED?

Comment: Yes they are in fact green LEDs, I've tried blue ones but they require too high of a voltage, resulting in the transistores getting very hot while still driving as usual

Comment: You should try maybe a yellow LED, but check the threshold voltage of each MOSFET and let me know.

Comment: My green and yellow LEDs behave the same..

also, I sadly have no way to measure current since the fuses in my multimeter are blown and I don't have replacements, although I have an arduino and a 0.5 ohm resistor but I don't think that the 10 bit ADC will have a fine enough resolution to properly measure the voltage across the resistor, plus it'll modify the result - scrap that

Comment: You don't need to measure the actual current, you only need to see the point of turn-on, because it happens fairly sharply and rapidly, so an LED in series with a large resistor will let you know when that happens. Also, instead of an LED, you could use 4-6 small signal diodes like 1N4148. Start with 4 and then add another one. You could also use a RED LED with a 4148 in series, it might give you just above 2V which might be just what you need.

Comment: Using RED LEDs with 4148s results in the P-FET getting hot and the N-FET gettign warm, Voltages are +2.5V and -2.7V (Gate - 0V), 4.5V and 4.8V (Gate - Drain) and +2.7 and -2.45V (Gate - Source) respectively

also, I only have a total of two 4148s bu I have a *lot* of 4007 diodes

Comment: The LM358 dual opamp is never used for audio because it produces crossover distortion and hissss. It also has trouble producing frequencies above only 2kHz. Your Mosfets are not biased enough by the diodes so they also produce crossover distortion. Their datasheets show that the turn-on voltage (threshold voltage) is higher than from 2V to 4V. The Mosfets have a high input capacitance that might overload the opamp or cause it to oscillate..

Comment: @mineing You could also use the 4007. I would like to know if you had any improvement with the sound with these changes. I have never tried building an amp with MOSFET's like this, I did have a successful build on the first try of a 60W amplifier with only BJTs and no ICs.